# transactions for waterline on multiple models

Tags: transactions, sails.js, waterline

I am using Sails waterline mysql adapter to manage a database,

Suppose I have two models, Customer and Contract, when I create a contract, I need to also find or create this customer. But it is possible that I created this customer, then contract failed to create. So I am trying to get the transaction way of doing it.

From https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/62 I found out about transaction on one model. such as find and create

```
Customer.transaction().findOne({name:"aaa"}).done(function(err,data){
 if(err) data.rollback(callback); 
 if(!data)//does not exist
 Customer.create({name:"aaa"}).done(function(err,data2){
data.save().commit()
});
});
```

However, say if I need to create two models, both models should be either created or not created. Like if contract failed, then the client should not be created neither. How do I do it?

```
 Customer.transaction().create({name:"aaa"}).done(function(err,client){
 if(err) return client.rollback(callback); 
 Contract.create({contractname:"bbb"}).done(function(err,contract){
 if(err) return client.rollback(callback);
   client.save().commit()
 });
 });
```

will this client.save() also control the Contract model?

Thanks

Comment: any news on that? =)

Comment: Glad to know someone also had this problem haha. check my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really check the source code on transaction(). Then I end up doing something else:

I first create a nativeQuery function to make the query call in a promise

```
nativeQuery=function(query){
    var promise=Promise.defer();
    [AnyModel].query(query,function(err,data){
        if(err) promise.reject(err);
        promise.resolve(data);
    });
    return promise.promise;
}
```

Then I used the old fashion start transaction syntax

```
nativeQuery('START TRANSACTION').then(function(){
    do stuff
}).then(function(data){
    return nativeQuery('COMMIT');
}).fail(function(err){
    return nativeQuery('ROLLBACK');
});
```

Didn't really use the waterline transaction stuff...